# How to subscribe to an event in Yahoo YUI 2.0?

Tags: javascript, yui, yahoo

So I have a datatable and that shows a whole bunch of data, one column of which I want to be editable inline through the use of a set of radio Buttons. The relevant code is here:

```
{key: "SessionOccurred", label: "Did Session Occur?", editor: new YAHOO.widget.RadioCellEditor({radioOptions:["Yes","No","N/A"], disableBtns:false })},
```

Now below this code, I want to subscribe to the event where a cell i clicked on and this set of radiobuttons with the options "yes", "no" and "n/a" appears.  To do that, i use the following code:

```
    Ex.myDataTable.subscribe("cellClickEvent", Ex.myDataTable.onEventShowCellEditor);         
    Ex.myDataTable.subscribe("cellClickEvent", function(oArgs){
        alert('success');})
```

I just cannot get this radioClickEvent subscription to trigger though.  The "cellClickEvent" subscription definitely does trigger, because when I click on a cell, the radiobutton options appear.  But I just can't get the function to trigger with the radioClickEvent.

If anyone could share any ideas on what I may be doing wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks a lot ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to combine it to one subscribe call:

```
Ex.myDataTable.subscribe("cellClickEvent", function (oArgs) {
    Ex.myDataTable.onEventShowCellEditor(oArgs);
    alert('success');
});
```